# Unable to change foldmethod

Tags: folding

I have the following simple line:

`inoremap <silent> <TAB>      <C-o>:set foldmethod=manual<cr>`

However, after this command is run and I run set foldmethod?, it reports the foldmethod is still set to syntax.

To be sure this map is getting triggered, I added

`<C-o>:set fdm=manual <bar> :let blah = 222<cr>` to the map and `echo blah` reports 222 as expected.

Comment: Your mapping works, I just tested it. You may have another map on `<tab>` or `<c-i>` (which is the same key, at lest in a terminal). `verbose map <tab>` can tell you more.

Comment: Hmm, says "no mapping found" for both <tab> and <c-i>.

Comment: There's some dark magic involved here. Sorry I can't help you more...

Comment: I’m wondering if the local and global foldmethods are different